# How to get average of data with a '$' in the string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data set:

```
               Year                   Total
               2019                      $.00
               2018                      $.00
               2017                   $110.00
               2016                      $.00
               2015                      $.00
               2014                    $70.00
               2013                    $50.00
               2012                    $50.00
               2011                      $.00
               2010                      $.00
```

Each

Using the following simple query I am attempting to return the average of these numbers but I continue to get the ORA-01722 Invalid Number error.

```
select to_char(avg(Total)) level_1
 from Fulldata
```

I have also tried to use the following with the same result:

```
select to_char(avg(Total), 'L999G999G999D99') level_1
 from Fulldata
```

Is there a different way to create the average of this data set and furthermore, to create the 5 year average from just the past 5 years?

Comment: Why are you storing a numeric value as a string in the first place? Particularly if they are always the same currency - but even if they're different, it would probably be more convenient to store the numeric value and have another column to indicate the currency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nls_numeric_characters` option for `to_number` function

```
select avg(to_number('$112.05', 'fm$999G999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters=''.,'''))  
       as level_1
  from Fulldata
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `replace()`?

```
select avg(to_number(replace(Total, '$'))) as level_1
from Fulldata
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a number with an explicit format model that allows for the currency sign, then get the average, then convert back to a string:

```
select to_char(avg(
  to_number(total, 'L999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY=''$''')), 
                   'L999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY=''$''') as level_1
from fulldata;

LEVEL_1                  
-------------------------
                   $28.00
```

or more simply with fixed currency and group/decimal characters:

```
select to_char(avg(to_number(total, '$999,999,999.99')), '$999,999,999.99') as level_1
from fulldata;

LEVEL_1         
----------------
          $28.00
```

If you only want the average over five years of data then filter for that; either:

```
select to_char(avg(to_number(total, '$999,999,999.99')), '$999,999,999.99') as level_1
from fulldata
where year < extract(year from sysdate)
and year >= extract(year from sysdate) - 5;

LEVEL_1         
----------------
          $36.00
```

or

```
select to_char(avg(to_number(total, '$999,999,999.99')), '$999,999,999.99') as level_1
from fulldata
where year >= extract(year from sysdate) - 4;

LEVEL_1         
----------------
          $22.00
```

... depending on whether you want to include the current year (i.e. 2014-2018 in the first version, or 2015-2019 in the second).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e98986f68811b31e3e897f6bba87eb31)